# BERT encoding layer produces same output for all inputs during evaluation (PyTorch)

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, pre-trained-model, bert-language-model

I don't understand why my BERT model returns the same output during evaluation. The output of my model during training seems correct, as the values were different, but is totally the same during evaluation.
[image: Output during evaluation]

Here is my BERT model class

```
class BERTBaseUncased(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(BERTBaseUncased, self).__init__()
        self.bert = BertModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
        self.bert_drop = nn.Dropout(0.3)
        self.out = nn.Linear(768, 4)

    def forward(self, ids, mask, token_type_ids):
        _, o2 = self.bert(ids, attention_mask=mask, token_type_ids=token_type_ids) # Use one of the outputs
        bo = self.bert_drop(o2)
        return self.out(bo)
```

My dataset class

```
class BERTDataset:
    def __init__(self, review, target, tokenizer, classes=4):
        self.review = review
        self.target = target
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer
        self.max_len = max_len
        self.classes = classes

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.review)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        review = str(self.review)
        review = " ".join(review.split())

        inputs = self.tokenizer.encode_plus(review, None, add_special_tokens=True, max_length= self.max_len,
                                            pad_to_max_length=True, return_token_type_ids=True,
                                            return_attention_masks=True)

        ids = inputs["input_ids"]
        mask = inputs["attention_mask"]
        token_type_ids = inputs["token_type_ids"]

        return {
            'ids': torch.tensor(ids, dtype=torch.long),
            'mask': torch.tensor(mask, dtype=torch.long),
            'token_type_ids': torch.tensor(token_type_ids, dtype=torch.long),
            'targets': torch.tensor(to_categorical(self.target[item], self.classes), dtype=torch.float)
        }
```

My evaluation function

```
def eval_fn(data_loader, model, device):
    model.eval()

    total_loss = 0.0

    with torch.no_grad():
        for bi, d in tqdm(enumerate(data_loader), total=len(data_loader)):
            ids = d['ids']
            token_type_ids = d['token_type_ids']
            mask = d['mask']
            targets = d['targets']

            ids = ids.to(device, dtype=torch.long)
            token_type_ids = token_type_ids.to(device, dtype=torch.long)
            mask = mask.to(device, dtype=torch.long)
            targets = targets.to(device, dtype=torch.float)

            outputs = model(
                ids=ids,
                mask=mask,
                token_type_ids=token_type_ids
            )

            loss = loss_fn(outputs, targets)
            total_loss += loss.item()
```

And my training function

```
def train_fn(data_loader, model, optimizer, device, scheduler):
    model.train()

    total_loss = 0.0

    for bi, d in tqdm(enumerate(data_loader), total=len(data_loader)):
        ids = d['ids']
        token_type_ids = d['token_type_ids']
        mask = d['mask']
        targets = d['targets']

        ids = ids.to(device, dtype=torch.long)
        token_type_ids = token_type_ids.to(device, dtype=torch.long)
        mask = mask.to(device, dtype=torch.long)
        targets = targets.to(device, dtype=torch.float)

        optimizer.zero_grad()

        outputs = model(
            ids=ids,
            mask=mask,
            token_type_ids=token_type_ids
        )

        loss = loss_fn(outputs, targets)
        total_loss += loss.item()
        loss.backward()

        optimizer.step()
        scheduler.step()

    return total_loss/len(data_loader)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you passing mask during evaluation? Is it needed?

Comment: Is it possible that it is the issue?

Comment: Not exactly, sure.  can you share your training script too.

Answer (score 7):

In case anybody else has the problem, perhaps you forgot to use one of the recommended learning rates from the official paper:  `5e-5`, `3e-5`, `2e-5`

Gradients seem to polarize if the learning rate is too high, such as `0.01`, causing repeatedly the same logits for the val set.

Comment: This solves the issue, not the same logits at the validation, but it doesn't tell why. I see that at the training step output is different but at the validation it is the same. This is because gradients seem to polarize? Why?

Answer (score -1):

In your training code, you're not returning the trained model.

It seems you're training your model inside a function without returning it. The weight will be lost after the function ends. Hence, in the evaluation part, the model outputs random values.

```
def train_fn(data_loader, model, optimizer, device, scheduler):
    model.train()

    total_loss = 0.0

    for bi, d in tqdm(enumerate(data_loader), total=len(data_loader)):
        ids = d['ids']
        token_type_ids = d['token_type_ids']
        mask = d['mask']
        targets = d['targets']

        ids = ids.to(device, dtype=torch.long)
        token_type_ids = token_type_ids.to(device, dtype=torch.long)
        mask = mask.to(device, dtype=torch.long)
        targets = targets.to(device, dtype=torch.float)

        optimizer.zero_grad()

        outputs = model(
            ids=ids,
            mask=mask,
            token_type_ids=token_type_ids
        )

        loss = loss_fn(outputs, targets)
        total_loss += loss.item()
        loss.backward()

        optimizer.step()
        scheduler.step()

    return model, total_loss/len(data_loader) # this will help
```

Comment: check out the `forward` function.

Comment: I think the issue is then the function, you train the model inside a function without returning the model, the weights are lost once the function ends.

Comment: Damn.... this is definitely the issue. How come I didn't think of that. Thanks so so much.

Comment: Yes, I somehow missed that too in the first case. I was assuming you're using BertforSeq.

Comment: can you provide a sample output? what do you mean by same?

Answer (score -1):

The issue was from my dataloader class. I passed the whole dataset instead of just a single row.

```
def __getitem__(self, item):
        review = str(self.review[item])
        review = " ".join(review.split())
```

This solves it. Thanks to Zabir Al Nazi for the assistance.